# how to add new chrome driver path in selenium?

Tags: eclipse, selenium

i got got SessionNotCreatedException,  so i installed new version of chrome driver, i pressed delete on old path then eror msg came.
can any one suggest me the way out.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@Pratheeksha Nayak, this happens as your old chromedriver.exe is still in use. So restarting the machine or deleting the chromedriver.exe process from the task manager should resolve this.